# Playwright => Allow all cookies automatically

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm writing a Python script using playwright. I would like to allow the cookies before taking the associated snapshot of any website.
Do you know how to handle this ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do that using setCookies function check out this one,

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch()
        context = await browser.new_context()
        
        # Enable cookies
        await context.set_cookies([
            {
                "name": "cookie_name",
                "value": "cookie_value",
                "domain": "example.com"
            }
        ])

        # Navigate to website and take a snapshot
        page = await context.new_page()
        await page.goto('https://example.com')
        await page.screenshot(path='example.png')

        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Dear @Abdullahi Ashik Md. Arefin, thank you for your quick answer.
Unfortunately, I receive this error :
`code`
    await context.set_cookies([
AttributeError: 'BrowserContext' object has no attribute 'set_cookies'
`code`